# System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts [ <fn> shortcut not working ]

Tags: release-loki, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I am currently using elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) and I accidentally changed volume down (default: *< fn>F12*).
Now I can't change it back. Then I noticed that all shortcuts with *< fn>* are set/lebeled with  which is not true. All other shortcuts are working fine.

Now the question is how to reset it or change it back.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **xbindkeys** and **dconf-editor**.
[Here's your solution.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7628/loki-media-keys-shortcuts-volume-keys-broken)