# Brightness Controls not Working with NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: brightness

Despite multiple attempts switching between different version of NVIDIA drivers, the only video driver that will allow my laptop display brightness to change (via either settings or hotkey) has been the Noveau driver.

I saw a similar post on here somewhere about a System 76 laptop that was unable to change the brightness, but the workaround looked a little above my head. Anyone else experiencing this issue and found a solution?

Comment: It sounds like a potential hardware issue...

Answer (score 1):

I can't change the display brightness via FN-Hotkey either. It work's on the energycontrol-settings.

What's the downside of the nuveau-driver for laptops?

I do have another problem, probably related to the nvidia-driver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1628929?comments=all

Now, I want to try the nuveau-driver...

Quick edit: My starting point was the nuveau-driver. So, on nuveau-driver I can't change display brightness via hotkey. 
I installed the nvidia driver, and can't change the brightness via hotkey, either. Sad.

Answer (score -1):

Check this post. Should be the same logic for you brightness keys
You need correct key binding in d-conf

[Loki - Media Keys, Shortcuts, Volume Keys broken](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7628/loki-media-keys-shortcuts-volume-keys-broken)

Comment: From what I could tell from that post the issue was the hotkeys not assigning correctly/not doing anything when pressed without manually setting them up.

Comment: My hotkeys will recognize and bring up the brightness meter whenever I go to change the brightness. Just nothing happens when I do that. The meter will change as I press the keys but the brightness does nothing.